# fastest way to split files by unique group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, unix, split

What is the fastest way to split a very large file and write it to disk.

For e.g if I have data like

```
chr    a_val    b_val   a_idx
2      1355     25d     abd
2      1785     25d     abd
2      1825     36g     ahj
3      1125     25d     abd
3      1568     25d     aky
3      2398     g67     abd
3      1125     25d     afd
3      1525     25d     abd
3 ....................
4 ..........
4 ........
```

Where I want to split by "chr" values.

I was thinking of applying pandas method in the following way:

```
my_df = pd.read_csv("my_file.txt", sep='\t')
my_df = my_df.groupby('chr')

# split the file
for chr_, data in my_df:
    pd.Dataframe.to_csv(data, 'data_' + chr_ + '.txt', sep = '\t', header = True, index=False)
```

Pandas is very fast. But, would there be any other unix, linux or python based process method to do so in the fastest way possible.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the file sorted?

Comment: yes. this file is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

One liner python approach using list comprehension:

```
[group.to_csv(data, 'data_' + index + '.txt', sep = '\t', header = True, index=False) for index, group in my_df.groupby('chr')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk and expecting the data to be sorted on the chr column:

```
$ awk '
NR==1 {                       # store the header 
    h=$0                      # to var h
    next
}
{
    if(p!=$1) {               # when chr changes
        close(p)              # close previous file
        p=$1                  # new chr, new file identifier
        $0=h ORS $0           # add header 
    }
    print > "data_" p ".txt"  # output record to file
}' file
$ cat data_2.txt              # sample output
chr    a_val    b_val   a_idx
2      1355     25d     abd
2      1785     25d     abd
2      1825     36g     ahj
```

If the file is not sorted, you'll get extra headers in the files. In that case you could:

```
$ awk '                    # commented only the modified parts
NR==1 {
    h=$0
    next
}
{
    if(p!=$1) {
        close(p)
        p=$1
        if((p in a)==0) {  # if current chr hasnt been seen before ie. new file
            $0=h ORS $0    # write the header 
            a[p]           # hash the chr to a
        }
    }
print >> "data_" p ".txt"  # append to the file
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix/Linux approach:

```
head -1 my_file.txt && tail -n +2 my_file.txt | sort -n
```

`head` and `tail` here will ignore the header in `my_file.txt` and sort other lines.

`-n` option for `sort` will sort by numerical value.

Comment: the question was about splitting the files in the fastest way possible.